# How to get the id of the textbox on keydown event of that textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have a text box in my page:

```
<td>
<input type="text" id="Approvers1" size="11" onkeydown="AddUsersKeyDown(event)" style="width: 470px;" />
</td>
```

This is my js function:

```
function AddUsersKeyDown(evtobj) {

    if (evtobj.keyCode == 75 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {

        AddUsers(--input parameter--);
    }
}
```

Now if i press ctrl k in my textbox it must call another javascript function named AddUsers(--input parameter--).. where the **input parameter should be the id of the textbox**...

How to achieve this.. Either i need the id of the textbox or atleast the DOM object so that i can access the id of textbox from DOM object..

Kindly help me in achieving either one of the two things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to get the DOM element or `this.id` to get the id of the element

```
<td>
<input type="text" id="Approvers1" size="11" onkeydown="AddUsersKeyDown(event,this.id)" style="width: 470px;" />
</td>

function AddUsersKeyDown(evtobj,id) {

    if (evtobj.keyCode == 75 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {

        AddUsers(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's working fine... but 'k' is getting typed in my textbox... how to avoid that..

Comment: Am calling the AddUsers function only if the key pressed is ctrl k... so k is getting appended in textbox

Comment: Use evtobj.stopPropagation(); to stop the further propagation after calling the function

Comment: Getting script error as " Object doesn't support this property or method" at the line evtobj.stopPropagation(); in IE8...

Answer (score 4):

First you should rename the function to `AddUsersKeyDown` so the keydown event will be triggered. On the event object, there is a `target` property, which have the triggering DOM element. You can use that information to get the id.

```
 <input type="text" id="Approvers1" size="11" onkeydown="AddUsersKeyDown(event)" style="width: 470px;" />
```

And the Javascript:

```
function AddUsersKeyDown(evtobj) {

    var target = evtobj.target || evtobj.srcElement;

    if (evtobj.keyCode == 75 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
        AddUsers(target.id);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q26Nv/3/

Comment: getting script error in target.id in IE8... In chrome and firefox its working fine

Comment: The fiddle was not updated, only the example.. :) Take a look now!

Comment: Thank u working fine... But 'k' is getting typed in my text box... how to prevent that..

Comment: Add a `return false;` after `AddUsers()` I have updated the fiddle and the example.

Answer (score 2):

get 
[jquery](http://jquery.com/) here

and then take of onkeydown

```
<input type="text" id="Approvers1" class="keydown" size="11" style="width: 470px;" />
```

add script

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.keydown').keydown(function() {
       console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
});
<script>
```

maybe a lot of code, but you can be sure it's cross browsers
[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
function AddUserKeyDown(evtobj) {
    evtobj = evtobj || window.event;
    var target = evtobj.target || evtobj.srcElement;

    if (evtobj.keyCode == 75 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
       AddUsers(target.id);
    }
}
```

(Your func names don't match btw)